# Run time error '9': subscript out of range when generating an array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate a population for a GA. I used a 2d array to help generate a population. First the user will enter the population size and then the chromosome length, into a `UserForm`.

My variables:

```vb
Dim Generation As Integer
Dim Chromolength As Integer
Dim varchromolength As Integer
Dim Poparr() As Integer
```

Then I fetch the values from the `UserForm`:

```
PopSize = PopulationSize.value
aVariables = AOV.value          'assign userform value entered to this variable
varchromolength = Chromolengthentered.value    'assign userform value entered to this   variable
Chromolength = varchromolength * aVariables   'Chromosome length equals the length of     each varaible chromosome combined
```

The coding where the error occurs:

```vb
For i = 1 To PopSize           
    For j = 1 To Chromolength       
        If Rnd < 0.5 Then           
            Poparr(i, j) = 0   'assign o to gene
        Else
            Poparr(i, j) = 1   'assign 1 to gene     
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your code, you never assign the dimensions of the array. To do so, insert this line before your for loop, after setting the values of `PopSize` and `ChromoLength`.

```
Redim Poparr(1 to PopSize, 1 to ChromoLength)
```

**Unnecessary details:** You could just run `Redim Poparr(PopSize, ChromoLength)` but that would result in arrays that were `0 to Popsize` etc... unless you add `Option Base 1` to the top of your module. The default base for arrays is 0. I feel that it is better to explicitly indicate the lowerbound and upperbound of your array because the default can be 0 or 1 depending on the context.